# Spring , image path does not include AWS domain

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3

I'm new to Spring and  i'm trying to serve images from Amazon S3,for now I'm able to upload images, but when I try to access them via an end-point I don't see the aws domain in the path , in Django I used to pass the reqeuest context in the serializer but I don't know how to do it in Spring.

The response look like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgCXu.png)

I need the domain in the image Path

Comment: Do you want to simply reference the images by URL in a web page or do you want your Spring Services to read the images and do something with the byte[]. I will answer this showing both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access images in an Amazon S3 bucket from a Spring app, you can use the **AWS SDK for Java V2**. For example, assume you want to read the image and return it as a byte array to pass to another AWS Service or download it in the browser.

Using the  **S3Client** object's **getObjectAsBytes** method, you can get the image using the bucket name and key as the input.

```
public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {

        s3 = getClient();

        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key(keyName)
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();
            return data;

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If on the other hand, you want to get a URL of an object in an Amazon S3 bucket, you can get this information as well using the the  **S3Client** object's **s3.utilities().getUrl** method.

Example:

```
public static void getURL(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName ) {

        try {

            GetUrlRequest request = GetUrlRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(keyName)
                    .build();

            URL url = s3.utilities().getUrl(request);
            System.out.println("The URL for  "+keyName +" is "+url.toString());

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

This returns a value like:

**https://bucketxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/people.png**

To see the object using an URL like this - ensure that you have set the object to be read by public - otherwise the URL does not display the image. More infor here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

If you do not know how to code using the AWS SDK for Java V2, start here:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)